# If $\phi$ is a differentiable bijection from [a,b] to [c,d], is the derivative continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\phi$ is a differentiable bijection from [a,b] to [c,d], is the derivative continuous?

I have seen a counterexample in the case where the domain and range are unbounded intervals such as the positive reals. Like here:

[Does there exist a bijective differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$, whose derivative is not a continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415204/does-there-exist-a-bijective-differentiable-function-f-mathbbr-rightarrow)

But I was wondering if the statement is true for differentiable bijections that maps compact set to compact sets (specifically closed intervals). If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Please un-mark my answer as the accepted one, so that I can delete it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it is unmarked now

Comment: Thank you.${}{}$